# Animate property with storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I know there are several examples of how to animate a storyboard when they contain a target. for example animating the width of a button or the color of a rectangle.

I will like to animate a property with a storyboard and that property happens to be binded to other things. as a result I have something like:

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="sbVolume">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="{Binding SbVolumeValue}" To="40">           
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

**Code behind:**  (I also implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
    double _SbVolumeValue;
    public double SbVolumeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _SbVolumeValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _SbVolumeValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SbVolumeValue");
        }
    }
```

when I animate that storyboard is get the exception:

> > No target was specified for 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'.

I don't want to animate a target I just want to animate my property. how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe the *Remarks* section in [Storyboard.TargetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx) is of some help. It explains what happens if you do not specify the target object of an animation in a Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `TargetName` error you are getting, you should show us the XAML code where the storyboard is actually getting applied...

Meanwhile I am sure that

```
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="{Binding SbVolumeValue}"
```

... is NOT a valid code! This is supposed to be specified with the name of the target dependency property and **not bound value** via `Binding`!

So something like ...

```
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
```

... **is correct** but something like ....

```
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="EmployeeName"
```

... **is not correct** as if it is not a dependency property.

I hope I am clear!

Comment: I know that... so that means it will not be possible to animate just a property by itself? that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You cannot animate a non dependency property. Also you cannot animate it by Binding. Plus when applied via Triggers the storyboard would either revert back to original value of the proprty (i.e. 0) or always stay at To value (40) by locking the property refraining it from any other typ of modification to that dep prop.